# Why does Microsoft not allow unsigned themes in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, themes

I'm just curious as to WHY Microsoft does not allow custom themes in their Windows operating system. The foundation had existed since the days of XP, they have just disabled this feature since they officially introduced graphical themes in Windows XP. I know how to get past the restriction, and enjoy my theme, I'm just curious as to why such useful functionality was intentionally DISABLED? Windows (except RT) allows any software to be installed, and has a built-in function to replace the entire EXPLORER shell, why would they block themes not signed by them?

Comment: Simply stated.  Malicious themes we're a problem before they blocked it

Comment: @Ramhound Users can still install malicious "theme manager" software, so banning UXTheme-based themes doesn't lower the chance of the user installing malware. In fact, it increases said chance since it is A LOT easier to make an executable file malware compared to an .msstyles theme file.

Comment: Your logic makes no sense.  You asked "Why Microsoft does not allow custom themes" then you say "Users can still install theme manager software".  **So basically it still is possible to install custom themes.**  Most people won't install custom software to install a theme, thus limiting the exposer to malicious theme files.

Comment: @Ramhound let me rephrase: Microsoft does not allow custom themes to be installed natively without some executable that either patches the UXTHEMES.dll, injects something into explorer, or replaces explorer alltogether. `"Most people won't install custom software to install a theme, thus limiting the exposer to malicious theme files."`  Exactly my point. If there was a built-in way to install themes, more people would install themes, since there would be no need of custom software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows makes extensibility easy by having very explicit contracts on what the system will do, and what the program you write must do.  Microsoft places a high value on backwards compatibility, and if they were to document the interfaces for making a custom theme (via replacing `themeui.dll`), they would be expected not to break it with each release, which would severely limit their ability to iterate on their UI design.

Every version of windows since XP has made significant changes to the general appearance and operation of the various parts of the UI.  Maintaining a compatible contract through the many iterations would be a nightmare ([small example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/11/14/10236654.aspx)).

Beyond that, shell programming is HARD.  You not only have to anticipate the failures of your own code, but the code of the process you are loaded into.  The other modules you are forced to play with do [funny](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/08/03/10192225.aspx) [things](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/01/08/10487884.aspx) with [global state](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx), and generally make your life difficult.  And since the crash report says "explorer.exe", any failure of your code makes Microsoft look bad.

If those were not enough technical reasons, changing the visual appearance further fragments the "Windows" identity in much the same way that Android is currently having an identity crisis.  It complicates training, and at the end of the day really doesn't do anything to significantly improve the usability of the system.

Comment: Since my question got locked (I see why -- its philosophical in nature), and because your answer is well written and proves your point, I'll accept it ;) What your saying makes sense, though: allowing themes fragments the Microsoft brand.